# Checking if more than one option is selected in a Dropdown Multiple Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you hide/display specific content if more than one option is checked in a multiple select dropdown?

**HTML**

```
<select title="Choose option/s" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>

<span id="legendWasSelected" class="text-hard-light margin-left-xxs">One option was selected</span>
<span id="legendWereSelected" class="text-hard-light margin-left-xxs" style="display:none">More than one option was selected</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.selectpicker').change(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 1) {
        $('legendWereSelected:nth-of-type(2)').show();
    } else {
        $('legendWereSelected:nth-of-type(2)').hide();
    }
});
```

I haven't tested it but that should be about right, please tell me if there's an error

Comment: No problem, could you mark my answer as correct please, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the :selected selector, like this (Using jQuery):

```
$('#yourIDHere option:selected').length;
```

if length is greater than 1 you have more than 1 option selected

**EDIT : (based on Deckerz comment)**

you get selected values from multiselect using [jQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1)

```
var selectedValues = $('#yourIDHere').val();
```

Comment: Another thing to add is if you want to do something depending on the values you can use `var selectedValues = $('#yourIDHere').val();`

Comment: makes perfect sense !